# Automatically start SLAVE (mysql) Master Master

Tags: mysql, master-slave-replication

I performed the configuration of a database replication (slave), performed it as MASTER MASTER, however, every time I restart as machines, I need to manually start the slave

I use the command:

`START REPLICA USER = 'repl' PASSWORD = 'password';`

I want to know if I can define that when starting the system, the slave will automatically connect with this username and password...

If someone can help me...

I'm using mysql 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it, in the case when we are configuring the replica we use

```
CHANGE REPLICATION SOURCE TO 
    SOURCE_HOST = 'ipLocalMaquina1',  
    SOURCE_LOG_FILE = 'mysql-bin.00000x', 
    SOURCE_LOG_POS = 713, 
    SOURCE_SSL = 1;
```

However, I forgot to set the username, password and port;

I performed the following procedures:

Stop the slave:

```
Stop the replica;
```

Reset as slave settings:

```
reset replica;
```

Configure the file again, but now like this:

```
CHANGE REPLICATION SOURCE TO 
    SOURCE_HOST = '10 .158.0.24 ', 
    SOURCE_USER =' repl ', 
    SOURCE_PORT = 3306, 
    SOURCE_PASSWORD =' xxxxx ',   
    SOURCE_LOG_FILE =' binlog.000003 ', 
    SOURCE_LOG_POS = 156_, 
    SOURCE_SSL=1;
```

Start the slave:

```
start replica;
```

Answer (score 2):

After you setup your replication, go see if you have `skip-slave-start` in your `my.cnf`.

```
grep -c "^skip-slave-start" /etc/my.cnf
```

If you get 1 as a return, simply comment it out

```
#skip-slave-start
```

You may want to leave skip-slave-start to avoid split-brain scenarios occurring.

If you do this, it is at your own risk

Answer (score -1):

enable this line in the my.cnf (or my.ini) file.

```
skip-slave-start = FALSE
```

Comment: Nice advice, but that option is off by default. It's better to look for `skip-slave-start` and remove it.

Comment: I'm on ubuntu 20.04, the my.cnf file has nothing and the other files don't have this option, if you can help me